# Composition of functions, permutations of sequences

Tags: functions

I have come across this in a textbook:

Let $f = \langle2,1,3\rangle$ and $g = \langle1,3,2\rangle$ be permutations of $\{1,2,3\}$. Then $g \circ f = \langle 3,1,2\rangle$, $f \circ g = \langle 2,3,1\rangle$.

My intuition is that the results should be the opposite. What am I missing?

Comment: The permutation $\langle 2,1,3\rangle$ maps **A)** $2$ to $1$, $1$ to $3$ and $3$ to $2$, or **B)** maps $1$ to $2$, $2$ to $1$ and $3$ to $3$? If **A)**, the notation I know is $(2,1,3)$; if **B)**, I'd write $[2,1,3]$.

Comment: This was probably my confusion as well. The book doesn't expand on this in any way. It seems, though, that the author has implicitly assumed the mapping given by @martini.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why? We have - if I understand your notation correctly - 
\begin{align*}
  (g \circ f)(1) &= g\bigl(f(1)\bigr)\\
       &= g(2)\\
       &= 3\\
  (g \circ f)(2) &=  g\bigl(f(2)\bigr)\\
       &= g(1)\\
       &= 1\\
  (g \circ f)(3) &=  g\bigl(f(3)\bigr)\\
       &= g(3)\\
       &= 2
\end{align*}
Hence, $g \circ f = \langle 3,1,2\rangle$. Analogously, $f \circ g = \langle 2,3,1\rangle$.